# Tricks to make a small image to take up a large space on a webpage

Tags: images, resize, image-quality, image-editing

I need to create profile webpages for many people (100++ pages) and most of their profile photos (about 400x400) are small in dimension. But I have a large image space (1280x720) that I need to fill in on each page. What is the best way to fill in the empty space? Do I superimpose the small profile photo on a larger backdrop? If so, do you know any examples? Or do you know any better alternatives?

Comment: I'm afraid a sample image may be necessary. It's difficult to provide any suggestions without actually seeing the issue since "space" - large or small - is relative.

Comment: @Scott Profile photos are like 400x400 and the large space is like 1280x720

Comment: Were you hired as a 'page filler' or as a designer?

Answer (score 1):

I'd again ask for an image to show the overall layout.

One can not make adequate special suggestions without seeing a representation of *all* the elements in play. It's possible that nothing needs to be done. A great deal of space can promote a more professional appearance.

Based *purely* on measurements provided, I see no reason to "fill" a larger area with something to make a 400x400 headshot "fit better". I think it fits fine.

Of course, layout matters. Without more information, it's difficult to be more definitive.

[image: boss]

Answer (score 0):

If you really cannot modify the layout (i.e. reduce the space), I'd use a light, grayscale, low-contrast, low-information, blurred background image. Maybe one representing the organization somehow, maybe just something that fits the overall design.